# Python pipe-like stream object

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, io, thread-safety

I am looking for a Python class that:

- Is supported by Python 2.7
- Acts as an in-memory pipe with separate read and write pointers
- Is thread-safe
- Ideally, has methods that resemble the methods on regular file objects (`read`, `write`, etc.)
- Is ideally already in the Python standard library or at least accessible from pip

Does such a creature exist? Maybe `BufferedRWPair`, but the documentation for it is tragic:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BufferedRWPair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was looking for https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.mkfifo . It does exactly what I need.